# Finding double-spaces in a string - Python

Tags: python, string, find, double

Can anyone find a more Python'ic, more beautiful solution?

I’m looping through some text lines in a file, to check if they meet certain criteria.
For some reason it was decided that separators internally in the line is ‘  ‘, i.e. double space.

How do I check a text string to verify that all separators are exactly two spaces?
Spaces at the end of the line is not an issue, as the line is initially .strip()’ed.

I have written this, and it works – but it’s ugly.
The code will be shown to some Python newbie’s, so I’m looking for a shorter, clearer and more beautiful solution…

```
ll = ["53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W 25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2",
      " 53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2",
      "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2",
      "  53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2",
      "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2 ",
      "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2  ",
      "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W   25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2"]

for ln in ll:
    l = ln.strip()
    bolDS = True
    for n in range(len(l)-1):
        if (n>0 and l[n]==' ' and not ((l[n]==l[n+1])^(l[n]==l[n-1]))):
            bolDS = False

    print "|"+l+"|",bolDS
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def is_doublespace_separated(input_string):
    return '  '.join(input_string.split()) == input_string.strip()
```

This works because `string.split` will split your string on any whitespace.  and `string.join` joins the list with the separator `string`.  In this case, we use the separator `'  '` (two spaces) to re-join your string and then compare it against the stripped version (I sense you already know what strip does).

**This will ignore whitespace at the front of the string as well as at the end.

Comment: Nice little comparison. I would just delete the entire top part and make the edit your actual answer

Comment: @jdi -- Good point.  I always want to leave that stuff because I feel like I put a little work into it, but you're right that if it doesn't address the question, it should be deleted.

Comment: +1 clean answer. I'd help the next guy (e.g. my future self) with a `def is_doublespace_separated():` preceding it.

Comment: @msw : Turned it into a function -- Just for your future self ;).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick solution:

```
import re

s = "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W 25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2"
s2 = "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2"

def spaceTest(line):
    matches = re.findall(r'\s+', line.strip())
    return not any(m for m in matches if m != '  ')

print spaceTest(s)
# False
print spaceTest(s2)
# True
```

And one more little simpler approach:

```
s.strip().count('  ')+1 == len(s.split())
```

This assumes there should be 1 less amount of separators than there are fields.

Comment: Clever.  I like your second one.

Comment: @mgilson: Yours is a *hair* quicker

Comment: really?  I would have guessed yours to be faster.  We both have one `split` and one `strip`, I would expect `count` to be faster than `join` and the integer comparision is definitely faster than the string compare...  Weird.  Does string length matter?

Comment: @mgilson: It does scale both our performance outcomes but yours still seems to have a fraction of the edge

Comment: crazy python dev's not optimizing `count` as heavily as `join` I guess.  Thanks for doing the timing.

Comment: @mgilson: Its fun to compare these answers. I keep playing with the variations

Comment: For the re version `return [m for m in matches if m != '  '] == []` should be slightly faster. `return not any(m for m in matches if m != '  ')` should be if there are enough errors early enough in the strings.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Good eye! I updated with the `any` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

To verify that a line has only double-spaces you could use a regex (though
split/join solution by @mgilson might be both simpler and more efficient):

```
import re

ok = re.match(r'(?:\S|(?<!\s)  (?!\s))*$', line)
```

Note: it doesn't allow trailing double space before a newline, [example](http://ideone.com/ST1Lm).

Answer (score -3):

```
ll = ["53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W 25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2",
      " 53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2",
      "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2",
      "  53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2",
      "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2 ",
      "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W  25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2  ",
      "53.80  64-66-04.630N  52-16-15.355W   25-JUN-1993:16:48:34.00  S10293..  2"]

doubleSpace=ll.find("  ") #this code searches for double space.

print(doubleSpace)
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. And the question has asked to verify if all the separaters are two spaces. and not how many double spaces there are.